# Selenium IDE: How do I iterate simultaneously over 2 lists? I can't get the iterate over a collection to work

Tags: javascript, arrays, selenium-ide

I have a problem with selenium IDE, I need it to iterate over a list that has 2 values (for example username and password). I saw a section on selenium IDE's website for iterating over a collection but it does not seem to work for me:
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/control-flow

These are the 2 versions I tried, in the first one I tried to make a list but I am not sure I did correctly. In the 2 nd version of the code I try iterating over the 2nd list using array position (${MyArray}[0]}, it only works when the value is a number, when I try to replace it with ${count} it does not work anymore.

Any idea what I can do? Any help would be appreciated?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Am I the only one who has no idea what is being asked? If not, then you should post (without using embedded images) what your input is, what your desired output is and the JavaScript code you have tried to achieve this. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's not javascript code- it's code used inside SeleniumIDE which can also use javascript commands. This is specifically about using the ForEach command to iterate over 2 lists at the same time. The code is actually clearer when I paste a picture of it than if I write it down.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally found the solution for this in a reply to a blog post about arrays in Selenium IDE. You can't really do this through the forEach command, you have to use a javascript snippet through execute script command in order to iterate over the array. You can find the full answer here: https://sitegrammar.com/selenium-ide-arrays/#comment-91

This is the image of the full code that works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ybrkq.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also figured out what I've been doing wrong when trying to iterate over a collection. This is how the array should have been written:

execute script |   return [{name:"Angela",age:"55"},{name:"Linda",age:"50"}]  |    MyArray

forEach    |   MyArray   |   iterator

echo   | ${iterator.age}
end

This works for iterating over 2 arrays at the same time.